# JButton in JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I don't know why my grids cover my button I try to solve it out but I can't. Can anyone tell me why? Is it because, I put all together in BorderLayout? Any one can more the Play Button to the Right hand side of it ?

```
public game() {
        make();
        JPanel p = new JPanel();

        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        resetButton = new JButton("Play");
        p.add(playButton, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.add(p);
}
public void make(){
        frame = new JFrame("Gamer");

        frame.setTitle("Gamer");
        JPanel m = new JPanel(new GridLayout(9,9));
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                grids[i][j] = new JButton();
                m.add(grids[i][j]);
            }
        }
        frame.add(m, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setSize(width, heigth);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: `frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());` probably isn't helping. `JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout by default.

Comment: So i need to put it to other layout?

Comment: No, you just don't need to reset it, as it's loosing what was previously added to it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use **frame.add(p,BorderLayout.SOUTH)**

Here is an example.

The code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class game {
    JFrame frame;
    JButton grids[][] = new JButton[9][9];

    public game() {
        make();
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        JButton resetButton = new JButton("reset");
        JButton playButton = new JButton("Play");
        p.add(playButton);
        p.add(resetButton);
        frame.add(p,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void make() {
        frame = new JFrame("Gamer");
        frame.setTitle("Gamer");
        JPanel m = new JPanel(new GridLayout(9, 9));
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                grids[i][j] = new JButton();
                m.add(grids[i][j]);
            }
        }
        frame.add(m, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.pack();

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        game gameObj = new game();
    }
}
```

The effect:
[image]

Besides that,the first letter of the class name should be Capitalized.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, you are adding both the `m` (grid) and button panel to the `CENTER` position of the `BorderLayout`

Here

```
frame.add(m, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

and

```
p.add(playButton, BorderLayout.EAST);
frame.add(p); // adding to the CENTER position
```

The default position within the `BorderLayout` is the `CENTER` position.  By simply using `frame.add(p, BorderLayout.EAST);`, you can can move the button to the right...

[image: Layout]

Beware, there are issues with using `setResizable` where it will change the border size of the frame, changing the available space for your frames content, always call this before defining the size of the frame, which should be done with `pack`

You really want to avoid modifying the content of the frame after it's been made visible if you can, as this not only affects the space the content might like, but also needs you to `revalidate` and `repaint` the container.

Better, create the frame, then pass it to the `game` and `make` methods instead...

Answer (score 0):

You are using `frame.add(p)` - which may not add the panel to the correct area of the frame.
Try

```
frame.add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH)
```

or whatever? i.e. not `CENTER` which would overwrite your grid.

Also note that the layout of the panel hasn't been set, so it will be a `FlowLayout` by default.

As MadProgrammer said, no need to set the layout of the frame - especially *AFTER* adding the grids!

Finally, it is good practice to only add to the `getContentPane()` of a frame.

Answer (score 0):

Well, It is a matter of size.  Literally, your grid and/or button are too big to fit where you want them to, so they leak into the next space.  (i.e. BorderLayout.EAST will leak into BorderLayout.CENTER).

Try making your JFrame larger, and also try setting the preferred size of your JPanels to further assure a well built window.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this?

```
 ![enter image description here][1]import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class WelcomActivity {
    JFrame frame;
    JButton resetButton;
    JButton playButton;
    JButton[][] grids = new JButton[9][9];
    int width = 600;
    int heigth = 400;

    public void game() {
        make();
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        playButton = new JButton("Play");
        resetButton = new JButton("Reset");
        p.add(playButton);
        p.add(resetButton);

        frame.getContentPane().add(p, BorderLayout.EAST);
    }

    public void make() {
        frame = new JFrame("Gamer");

        frame.setTitle("Gamer");
        JPanel m = new JPanel(new GridLayout(9, 9));
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                grids[i][j] = new JButton();
                m.add(grids[i][j]);
            }
        }
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setSize(width, heigth);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout() );
        frame.getContentPane().add(m, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new WelcomActivity().game();
    }
}
```